# '500 Port command invalid' error in Windows ftp client

Tags: vba, windows, download, ftp

I've created a script to download a file from an FTP server using VBA to fire off the script. I can connect to the server and navigate to the correct directory, but when I got to get the file I get the message:

> 500 Port command invalid

I've tweaked the code as much as I can but I don't understand enough about ports or FTP to know what I need to change.

The VBA code:

```
Dim FTPcommand As String
Dim wsh As Object

FTPcommand = "ftp -n -s:" & Chr(34) & "C:\path\to\FTP_commands.txt" & Chr(34)
Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.Run FTPcommand, 5, True
```

The script:

```
open ftp.blahblahbah.bl
user username password
lcd C:\Users\me\Documents\location
cd /specific location/
get "file.xlsx"
```

I expect the file to download but get the following messages (after the script logs in and successfully navigates to the filepath):

> ftp> open ftp.address.com
>   Connected to ftp.address.com
>   220 Welcome to address.com
>   ftp> user USERNAME PASSWORD
>   ---> USER USERNAME
>   331 User USERNAME, password please
>   ---> PASS PASSWORD
>   230 Password Ok, User logged in
>   ftp lcd C:\Users\joe\Documents
>   Local directory now C:\Users\joe\Documents.
>   ftp> cd /location/
>   --->CWD /location/
>   250 Change directory ok
>   ftp get "file.xlsx"
>   ---> PORT 192.168.1.121.242.113
>   500 Port command invalid
>   RETR file.xlsx
>   425 Unable to open the data connection

Comment: Add `-d` switch to `ftp` command-line and show us a complete output.

Comment: Thanks Martin- now updated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ---> PORT 192.168.1.121.242.113
>   500 Port command invalid

It looks like the `ftp` is sending an internal IP address to an FTP server in another network. The server cannot connect to that IP address. I do not think, there's a way to solve it with `ftp`. The firewall/NAT of your network could solve it by translating IP address in the `PORT` command.

---

Or you need to use a different FTP client, which supports the FTP passive mode.

You can use [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/). There's a [guide to converting Windows `ftp` script to WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

The following WinSCP code is equivalent to yours:

```
Dim FTPcommand As String
Dim wsh As Object

FTPcommand = """C:\Path\To\winscp.com"" /ini=nul /script=""C:\Path\To\FTP_commands.txt"""
Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.Run FTPcommand, 5, True
```

The script:

```
open ftp://username:password@ftp.blahblahbah.bl/
lcd C:\Users\me\Documents\location
cd /specific location/
get "file.xlsx"
exit
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thankyou! It's working perfectly. Appreciate you taking the time to help